# Некорректный вывод сообщения JS в файле html

Tags: javascript, alert

Только начал покорять дебри программирования и уже столкнулся с ошибкой. Почему в сообщении, которое должно быть на русском, выводятся неизвестные символы при загрузке отдельного файла js? В файле одна команда `alert("что-то");`
Проблема от браузера не зависит. На английском текст выводится корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставь всем файлам кодировку utf-8 без bom

Comment: В vs code по умолчанию стоит эта кодировка без bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте мета в head страницы

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. В книге такой код без этой меты работал почему-то.